# os.listdir raises OSError, but path exists and is corectly passed to python

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, operating-system, listdir

I have a problem on ONE specific OSX machine used for auto-testing, that os.listdir raises OSError.

The funny thing is that:

```
os.path.exists("/Volumes/label_of_mounted_drive") -> True
os.path.isdir("/Volumes/label_of_mounted_drive") -> True
```

but

```
os.listdir("/Volumes/label_of_mounted_drive") -> OSError ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)
```

stat for the path is

```
posix.stat_result(st_mode=16877, st_ino=1, st_dev=939524119, st_nlink=2, st_uid=502, st_gid=20, st_size=68, st_atime=1523980718, st_mtime=1523980718, st_ctime=1523980718)
```

The drive is mounted, visible and usable in finder. I can list it via terminal. I can even list it via separate python process (e.g. calling subprocess and 'python', '-c', 'import os; print os.listdir("the_path_here")')

The even funnier part is that it was working 2 days ago, and now it stopped*.

In addition - running python in terminal - listdir works on this particular path, running tests via nosetests / unittests - listdir is broken.

Now this is NOT THE FIRST time this has happen on this particular machine. Last time I just reinstalled the whole system and it fixed it.
Now - I'm planning to do the same - but at this point **I'm just SUPER curious what is causing this.**

Any thoughts?

*it stopped working after I switched from virtualenv to pyenv-virtualenv. BUT after some time and many other tries, I uninstalled all brew packages and brew itself, created new fresh user, removed the old user, installed brew and python on new user from scratch, and went back to simple virtualenv, all to no success :(

Machine setup is:

- Sierra 10.12.6
- brew
- python@2
- xcode 9.2
- some of the installed libs are:

  - brew: zlib, libjpeg
  - python: matplotlib, Pillow, lxml, pyobjc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, importing matplotlib breaks this (tests are running on virtualenv). Why - I have no idea.
I moved drawing graphs to after tests are ran, and I'm importing matplotlib inside the method.

Comment: This is likely not the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research on this and it looks like these are things to try:

1. If you're trying to expand `/Volumes/label_of_mounted_drive`, then I believe that you should do `os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('/Volumes/label_of_mounted_drive'))`.
2. If you aren't already, use the full path. (Users/YOURUSERNAME/whatever)
3. If all else fails, try `os.chdir()`.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: /Volumes/ is like when you plugin your pen-drive or something its get mounted under /Volumes, or if you have multiple drives (partitions etc) all are listed under /Volumes. /Volumes is NOT under user space, but user space is "inside" /Volumes (like /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users) so the there is no point in making /Volumes relative to user space.
I'll try os.chdir.